# Fill DropDown list from data in database - Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to be able to add and remove items from LANGUAGES, instead of them being hardcoded like this. Now I get what I need, which is DropDown with 'English', 'German' and 'Italian' choice. Now i need them to be in a SQLite database and retrived from there, with option to add new languages and remove/edit existing. Thanks in advance...

```
LANGUAGES = [

        ("1", "English"),
        ("2", "German"),
        ("3", "Italian"),

    ]

language = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=LANGUAGES, default=1, null=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that with a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey), For example:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class MyModel(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

You can then populate the database with records for `Language`, and select the language for the `MyModel` objects.

If you use a `ModelForm`, then standard Django will make a dropdown with the options in the "target" model (and use `str(…)` to represent these objects).

It is probably better to set [**`unique=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#unique) for the `name` field, to prevent creating another `Language` object with the *same* name.

By setting [**`on_delete=models.PROTECT`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) we prevent removing a language, given `MyModel` refers with at least one object to that language. So you can only remove languages if no `MyModel` is referring to it anymore.

The database will normally guarantee *referential integrity*. That means that the `language` column stores the value of the primary key of the object it refers to. The database normally guarantees that if one such column contains a value *x*, then there is a primary key with that value in the table for `Language`.

Comment: I'm learning Python and Django, for a month now, so I'm really new at this, and You can imagine how happy I am now, after a day of google-ing and trying to resolve this, and now I have a solution thank's to You @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this in a form, create a new model for languages and populate the table.

```
class Language(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class MyLanguageForm(ModelForm):
    language = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Languages.objects.all())

    # The rest
```